# Generar un array de Objetos a partir de un Objeto

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Necesito generar un *array* que contenga diferentes objetos partiendo de una información que viene de un *objeto*.

La información la recibo de la siguiente manera:

```js
let question = {
  question1: " Indicar pretensiones de renta",
  answer1: "800.000",
  question2: "Indicar experiencia relacionada al cargo",
  answer2: "Jefe",
  question3: "¿eres una persona con discapacidad?",
  answer3: "no",
};
```

Y necesito generar un *array* de la siguiente manera:

```js
"answers": [
  {
    "text": "800.000",
    "question": "Indicar pretensiones de renta"
  },
  {
    "text": "Jefe",
    "question": "Indicar experiencia relacionada al cargo"
  },
  {
    "text": "$750.000",
    "question": "¿Cual es tu pretensión de renta? "
  },
  {
    "text": "no",
    "question": "¿eres una persona con discapacidad?"
  }
];
```

Es importante destacar que actualmente son 3 preguntas con 3 respuestas, pero pueden ser *N numero de preguntas*.

Actualmente, lo estoy tratando de realizar así:

```js
const answer = [];

for (const property in question) {
  let ultimoCaracter = property.charAt(property.length - 1);
  let text = property === `answer${ultimoCaracter}` ? question[property] : "";

  let question =
    property === `question${ultimoCaracter}` ? question[property] : "";

  answer.push({
    text: text,
    question: question,
  });
}

console.log(answer);
```

Obteniendo el siguiente resultado:

```js
[
  {
    text: "",
    question: " Indicar pretensiones de renta.",
  },

  {
    text: "800.000",
    question: "",
  },

  {
    text: "",
    question: " Indicar experiencia relacionada al cargo",
  },

  {
    text: "Jefe",
    question: "",
  },
  {
    text: "",
    question: "¿eres una persona con discapacidad?",
  },

  {
    text: "No",
    question: "",
  },
];
```

Me podrían, por favor, orientar cómo realizarlo.

Answer (score 3):

### Con la ayuda de un iterador

Para pasar de esto (`question`):

```js
const question = {
  question1: " Indicar pretensiones de renta",
  answer1: "800.000",
    ...
};
```

Al siguiente *array* de objetos de preguntas y respuestas:

```js
const answer = [
  {
    text: "800.000",
    question: "Indicar pretensiones de renta",
  },

  ...
];
```

> **Nota:** esta es una solución de muchas otras posibles.

Podrías convertir el objeto en un *array* de *claves* (propiedades) y luego, convertir esas *claves* (propiedades) en un iterador.

Pruebe la siguiente solución y después lea su explicación:

```js
const question = {
  question1: " Indicar pretensiones de renta",
  answer1: "800.000",
  question2: "Indicar experiencia relacionada al cargo",
  answer2: "Jefe",
  question3: "¿eres una persona con discapacidad?",
  answer3: "no"
};

const answer = [];

const propiedades = Object.keys( question );
let iterador = propiedades.values();

for ( let propiedad of iterador ) {
  let [pregunta, respuesta] = [propiedad, iterador.next().value];

  // Almacenamos el objeto en cada iteración (son tres
  // iteraciones):
  answer.push({
    question: question[pregunta],
    text: question[respuesta]
  });
}

console.log(answer);
```

#### Explicación

En la línea:

```js
const propiedades = Object.keys(question);
```

Hemos obtenido un *array* de propiedades (preguntas y respuestas) con `Object.keys( question )`.

Para obtener un iterador:

```js
let iterador = propiedades.values();
```

Con la ayuda del método `values()`.

Luego, en el bucle:

```js
for ( let propiedad of iterador ) {
    ...
}
```

Obtenemos las *claves* `question` y `answer` al mismo tiempo en cada iteración:

```js
let [pregunta, respuesta] = [propiedad, iterador.next().value];
```

Tome en cuenta, que `propiedad` es el valor actual definido en `pregunta` e `iterador.next().value` el siguiente valor definido en `respuesta`, que luego almacenaremos en nuestro *array* `answer`:

```js
answer.push({
  question: question[pregunta], // Pregunta
  text: question[respuesta], // Respuesta
});
```

Puede consultar **[`Array.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/values)** y **[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/keys)** para conocer un poco más sobre ellos.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda y la explicación David!

Comment: @evertofarias ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
    let question = {
        question1: ' Indicar pretensiones de renta',
        answer1: '800.000',
        question2: 'Indicar experiencia relacionada al cargo',
        answer2: 'Jefe',
        question3: '¿eres una persona con discapacidad?',
        answer3: 'no'
    };

    // guardara el nuevo object        
    let data = { "answers": [] };
    // recorremos el objetco
    for (x in question) {
        // sacamos el numero
        number = `${x}`.slice(-1);
        // extraemos el ultimo digito
        tipo = `${x}`.slice(0, -1);
        // validos que sea un pregunta
        if (tipo == "question") {           
            // creamos el objetc
            // la expresion ( question[`answer${number}`] || "" )
            // indica que si question[`answer${number}`] es null o undefined
            // text sera igual a nada "" viene a ser un or || 
            resultado={"question" : question[x] , "text" : question[`answer${number}`] || "" };
            // agregamos a resultado
            data.answers.push(resultado);
        }
    }
    console.log(data);
```

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta! Pero, considera explicar el código, pues puede haber usuarios que estén iniciando y se pierdan con el código empleado